# ASP.NET Core: Disable browser cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, caching, asp.net-core

I'm a newbie web developer, and ASP.NET Core is the first web framework I've worked with. I noticed that my site wasn't updating when I hit F5, and I tracked it down to the browser cache being enabled. If I open Chrome DevTools > Network and select 'Disable brower cache', my site gets updated properly.

However, I don't want to go through this process every time I start debugging. Is there a way to disable caching programmatically in my ASP.NET Core app, e.g. through the `Startup.cs` file, so that this will automatically be done for me?

**edit:** I am using `UseFileServer` instead of `UseStaticFiles`. (I am not sure what either does, but `UseFileServer` works correctly for debugging while `UseStaticFiles` does not.) I tried passing a `FileServerOptions` argument to `UseFileServer`, but that doesn't let you configure the cache expiry like `StaticFilesOptions` does.

If it's relevant, I'm building a Web API project.

Comment: @I.Manev See my updated description.

Comment: What about you disable caching on your browser instead.

Comment: Browsers have a few key commands to bypass caching like ctl+f5

Answer (score 5):

You can still use `StaticFileOptions` when using `UseFileServer`:

```
var fsOptions = new FileServerOptions();
fsOptions.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
{
    // Disable caching of all static files.
    context.Context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store";
    context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
    context.Context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "-1";
}
app.UseFileServer(fsOptions);
```

Comment: This is not correct. The `StaticFilesOptions` is a readonly property. Please edit your answer to be like this: `var fsOptions = new FileServerOptions(); fsOptions.StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = ...; app.UseFileServer(fsOptions);`. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for update.  That will teach me to work without an IDE.